# Cursor text doesn't change in PuTTY

Tags: putty, color-theme

I click on Colours, select Cursor Text and click modify, change it to the color I want and then launch the session. Cursor color is the same as the foreground color. Anyone else having this problem? Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`Cursor Text` is used to control the text colour when the cursor is over the text. If you want to change the cursor colour, you should change the `Cursor Colour` setting.

Illustrated below when `Cursor Text` was set to red and `Cursor Colour` was set to blue.

[image: PuTTY cursor text colour]

Answer (score 1):

Window-Colours:

To change the font color, you do not change the "Color Text", you need to change the "Default Foreground".

To change the Putty background, you need to change the "Default Background".

To change the cursor color you need to change "Cursor Color"

@cychoi above is correct, if you change the "cursor text" and you type something in putty and then you hit the arrow to the left, this will change that particular character that your cursor is on to the color that you selected for "cursor text".